# UIDatePicker not fully popping up on UITextField click

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uidatepicker

The app I'm coding is an event-based app. On the screen where you would create a new event I have a UITextField with a UIDatePicker set as its input view initialized as:

```
lazy var eventDateTxt: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Pick Your Event Date",
                                     attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.zipVeryLightGray])
        tf.font = .zipBody
        tf.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        
        tf.tintColor = .white
        tf.backgroundColor = .zipGray
        tf.textColor = .white
        tf.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        tf.minimumFontSize = 10.0;
        
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
        datePicker.minimumDate = Date()
        tf.inputView = datePicker
        
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged), for: .valueChanged)
        return tf
}()
```

dateChanged looks like this

```
@objc func dateChanged(sender: UIDatePicker){
        let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
        dateFormat.dateStyle = .long
        dateFormat.timeStyle = .short
        eventDateTxt.text = dateFormat.string(from: sender.date)
        
        event.startTime = sender.date
}
```

and although it doesn't matter, here is my code for the UITextFieldDelegate

```
extension NewEventViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == titleText {
            if textField.text == "Event Title" {
                textField.text = ""
            }
        }
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == titleText {
            if textField.text == "" {
                textField.text = "Event Title"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem: When I click the UITextField to open the DatePicker, it pops up as a small pop up view on the bottom of the screen and looks like this:

https://ibb.co/WBJ9GsN

note the very bottom of the image.

Now if you click the date at the bottom there it opens the DatePicker as expected and looks like this:

https://ibb.co/N7VvfX6

when doing so an error comes up in the consol

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d79ea0 'UIView-bottom-readableContentGuide-constraint' UILayoutGuide:0x60000379d340'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.bottom == UILayoutGuide:0x60000379d260'UIViewReadableContentGuide'.bottom   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2021-08-11 12:52:37.262846-0400 zip_official[93261:10730049] [DatePicker] UIDatePicker 0x7faa2732fe80 is being laid out below its minimum width of 280. This may not look like expected, especially with larger than normal font sizes.
```

Using the suggested breakpoint didn't lead me anywhere.

So my question: How do I make it so the DatePicker pops up immediately without the little bottom tab.

Answer (score 3):

This date picker thing is a lot of pain in the back. It changed twice for last two iOS versions. I had the same issue earlier and what I did was:

Make the date picker stick to the bottom (with some constant to place it a little above safe area). In your case, I would give it a frame.

```swift
let datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: eventDateTxt.frame.minX, y: eventDateTxt.frame.minY, width: view.frame.width, height: 150))
```

Some pseudo code (for iOS 14 and higher I guess):

```swift
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
```

If your iOS version < 14, then maybe do it with frames.

Answer (score 0):

For better UI output

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
}  else if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
    datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
}
```